# Session lost iis 7.0 asp classic

Tags: session, iis, azure, asp-classic

I have a azure server with IIS 7.0 that are running a asp classic site.

I'm experience problems with some users losing there sessions, when answering some assignments.
Some times the users lose the session every 15 min.

Session timeout is set to 120 min in the iis configuration. And in the code are thesession timeout also set to 120 min.

I tryed seaching on google for any anwser. The only thing i found, was it could be a miss configuration in the application pool. 
I have checked that every setting in application pool, is set too what google comes up with.

Anyone who have experienced this problem? Or any idea what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few points which you can check:

1) If you update your web.config or other file type that causes your asp website to recycle
2) If you update your site with a lot of files, and sp.net causes your asp website to recycle to recompile and preserve memory.
3) AppPool in IIS recycles. In IIS, check out the "Advanced Settings" of your AppPool. Property "Idle Time-out". Set to 0  or some higher number than default, which is 20. Also in IIS, check the "Recycling" settings of AppPool. You can enable or disable AppPool from recycling. Finally on the 2nd page of the wizard is a way to log to the Event Log each type of AppPool shut down.

Additionally maybe something in the code is making this problems. You can handle Application_SessionStart and Application_SessionEnd to be check what's going on with session. IsNewSession property in the HttpSessionState class you can check if a new session is created for the active user.